# Swagger UI: Prettify JSON

Tags: json, swagger-ui, prettify

Is there a way to make Swagger prettify the JSON on its own, without requiring the called library to output pretty JSON?  I can't seem to find anything on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is on the [projects's GitHub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/810).

You can configure via **web.xml**:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>swagger.pretty.print</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

or via **BeanConfig**:

```
config.setPrettyPrint(true)
```

I asked a similar question for the Swashbuckle library, [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/541). Still waiting for an answer from Swashbuckle team.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: year old question, and if you opened the link there is no answer, yet. Merely trying to help people find the information or push Swashbuckle team to answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, since it's asking about Swagger UI, not just the Swagger library.